# GetOrderPlaceRedirectUrl Doesn't redirect to the gateway secure page

Tags: magento2, php, module, payment-methods, redirect

I have the following issue, I generate payment module from the website: http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/payment-module

After deploying it and install it on my Magento 2 site, I can see the new payment module in the admin panel and on the checkout page. now I am trying to make a redirect to the secure page of the gateway payment by overriding the method `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl` like that:
[image]

Now I expect that on the checkout page when I select the new payment I will be redirected to the secure page of the gateway payment, but it didn't happen, I am using Magento 2.1.

Comment: This service generates payment module based on deprecated classes. Do not extend AbstractMethod class, more details about payment method implementation you can find on [Magento 2 dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/integration-intro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **Web2/TranzilaMethod/view/frontend/web/template/payment/web2tranzila2.html**

Replace button following code:

```
<button class="action primary checkout"
        type="submit"
        data-bind="click: continueToTranzilaMethod, enable: (getCode() == isChecked())"
        disabled>
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
</button>
```

Open **Web2/TranzilaMethod/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/web2tranzila2-method.js**

Code should be following:

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function ($, Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Web2_TranzilaMethod/payment/tranzilamethod'
            },

            /** Returns send check to info */
            getMailingAddress: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            },
            continueToTranzilaMethod: function () {
                this.selectPaymentMethod();
                $.mage.redirect(
                    'https://direct.tranzila.com/ttxwinshop'
                );

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

[More details check paypal express checkout as a sample](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Paypal/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/paypal-express-abstract.js)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried to implement your suggestion in two ways: 1. I just update the current files with the code that you wrote me here, and on the checkout page, I got the error message in the console: continueToTranzilaMethod is not defined, although that the method located in the tranzilamethod-method.js" 2. I generated a new payment module, and make the changes in the files that you wrote me, deploy it and then I get a different error message in the console (in the loading of the checkout page): http://prntscr.com/e2dtc8

Comment: while the param should be like that: http://prntscr.com/e2dvjp,, maybe you have any idea ?

Comment: Could you share web2tranzila2-method.js? Or share your module

Comment: Can you share your checkout_index_index.xml?

Comment: Yes, sure. This is the web2tranzila2-method.js: http://prntscr.com/e2zu67 and that is the file checkout_index_index.xml: http://prntscr.com/e2zuuh thanks for your help

Comment: Remove pub/static/*, run setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Hi, you right, it updates the files. Now I am getting the following error:http://prntscr.com/e3kfjm (it inside my custom file of the payment)

Comment: if I changed the $.mage to window.location= 'x' it redirect me to a new page, I want to host the page inside some Iframe or other containers, I just don't want to go out my site

Comment: Check updated answer, you need to define jQuery for $.